# Html- how to disable <a href>?

Tags: html, href

I created a button that open a modal window on click.

```
<a href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="signup-button gray-btn pl-pr-36" id="connectBtn"  data-role="disabled">Connect</a>
```

For some reason the `data-role="disabled"` doesn't work good.
How can I disable it?

Comment: Just remove the `href` attribute?

Comment: Just don't use an `<a />` element if you don't really want to create a link. You can add `cursor:pointer` to any element in CSS.

Comment: do not use `a` for buttons, they can't be disabled (not native, just workarounds). Use `button` tag.

Comment: the modal is still  opened

Comment: Do you want to disable the default action of the link or you want to disable the modal to open?

Comment: Also, what makes you think `data-role` will actually do something? By default, `data-*` attributes do not do anything at all - they exist to contain some information. Libraries like jQuery make use of them, though.

Answer (score 88):

You can use CSS to accomplish this:

```css
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<a href="somelink.html" class="disabled">Some link</a>
```

Or you can use JavaScript to prevent the default action like this:

```
$('.disabled').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Good idea, but this won't disable it. You can still use the tab to focus the link, and press enter to follow it.

Answer (score 9):

> I created a button...

This is where you've gone wrong. You *haven't* created a button, you've created an anchor element. If you had used a `button` element instead, you wouldn't have this problem:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-role="disabled">
    Connect
</button>
```

If you are going to continue using an `a` element instead, at the very least you should give it a `role` attribute set to `"button"` and drop the `href` attribute altogether:

```
<a role="button" ...>
```

Once you've done that you can introduce [a piece of JavaScript which calls `event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) - here with `event` being your click event.

Answer (score 4):

```
.disabledLink.disabled {pointer-events:none;}
```

That should do it hope I helped!

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#connectBtn').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        })
    });
</script>
```

This will prevent the default action.

Comment: Though very likely, considering jQuery isn't tagged you shouldn't post answers until further clarification is given. Your first approach here should have been to leave a comment asking *Are you using jQuery?* And, considering you didn't, what you should have definitely done is preface your answer with an *If you are using jQuery...*.