# How to add hyperlink to the column of a table using *ngFor in Angular2

Tags: html, angular, hyperlink

I have a table with 4 columns-Name, id, Dept, City and I'm providing both row data and column data as an array from a typescript file and iterating through *ngFor. Here is my piece of code

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor=let rowData of data | orderBy:convertSorting()>
       <td *ngFor=let column of columns>
            {{rowData[column.columnValue] | format:column.filter}}
       </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to provide a hyperlink to all the rows of second column i.e city so that if I click that, it should navigate to a new page to display detailed info.
How do I achieve it using *ngFor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let rowData of data | orderBy:convertSorting()">
       <td *ngFor="let column of columns; let idx=index">
            <span *ngIf="idx == 1">
                 <a href="your-target-url">{{rowData[column.columnValue] | format:column.filter}}</a>
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="idx != 1">
                {{rowData[column.columnValue] | format:column.filter}}
            </span>
       </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I disable the hyperlink on a certain condition? i.e. <span *ngIf="idx == 1 && showLink">. Here showLink is a boolean value and if it is false, id should be displayed but without hyperlink

Comment: define showLink in your component, then you can use it that way in your view :).

Comment: I've defined it in my component and it's value changes true/false accordingly and if it's false, I wanna make the hyperlink unclickable. How do I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318057/html-how-to-disable-a-href -- use the CSS there to make it unclickable, then dynamically apply the class to the link using ngClass and your showLink https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to add via TypeScript:

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor=let rowData of data | orderBy:convertSorting()>
       <td *ngFor=let column of columns>
            {{rowData[column.columnValue] | format:column.filter}}
       </td>
    <td (click)="LinktoCity(column.city)">{{city}}</td>

   </tr>
</tbody>
```

**TypeScript**

```
LinktoCity(city: string){        
        let mainLink = "www..."
        window.open(mainLink+city);
    }
```